# Insert custom post type with Custom field by using wp rest api

Tags: wordpress, rest

Hello i am unable to store the value of author field by using wp rest api. author is a custom field in custom  post type book.all other fields are stored correctly. it ignores all the custom field of custom post type book.

```
<?php 

$curl = curl_init();
$data = array(
'title' => "book 1",
'status' => "publish",
'content' => "Inserting data through rest api ",
'format' => 'standard',
'author' => 'Jaipur',
);
curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
CURLOPT_URL => "http://localhost/wp-json/wp/v2/book/",
CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
CURLOPT_ENCODING => "",
CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 10,
CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 30,
CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,
CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => "POST",
CURLOPT_USERPWD => "admin" . ":" . "admin",
CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array(
"cache-control: no-cache",
"Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
),


CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => http_build_query($data),
));

$response = curl_exec($curl);
$err = curl_error($curl);

curl_close($curl);

if ($err) {
echo "cURL Error #:" . $err;
} else {
echo $response;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to mention The ID for the author of the object. Not the name or something.
https://developer.wordpress.org/rest-api/reference/posts/#create-a-post

Comment: it is a custom field.

Comment: Each WP user have unique ID. You can get in wp-admin-> users-> edit user OR refer this wp api https://developer.wordpress.org/rest-api/reference/users

Comment: i am getting your point, ok but it ignores all the custom fields. only taking the value as per according default post type .

Comment: this question is something like this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35519680/how-to-correctly-create-custom-post-type-with-custom-fields-through-wp-rest-api

Comment: You can create custom post type use this https://developer.wordpress.org/rest-api/extending-the-rest-api/adding-rest-api-support-for-custom-content-types/